# Java 8: Build an Optional List out of sorted int values, but stop if specific boolean property is found (or prefer it via complex sort)

Tags: java, sorting, filter, lambda, java-stream

I'm interested in finding the most efficient way to filter, sort and collect from a List using streams, building my own Optional list, where I ultimately:

Sort objects, preferring those who match a particular string field,
otherwise sort by a different int field.

My straightforward approach is complex sort, preferring objects who return True to the string match, followed by the sort on the int field.  I haven't found a way to create a comparator that works easily with optionals. See pseudocode attempt below.

Another solution would be to perform a findFirst() for my string match, but also continue to collect and sort values if not found - don't know if something like this is possible.

Pseudocode for sort:

```
optionalX.matchedString().compareTo(optionalY.boolean.matchedString())
.thenCompares(optionalX.getValue().compareTo(optionalY.getValue()) 

List.stream list = vals.stream()
.filter (a && b && c)
.sorted(preference)
.collect.toList()
```

Java is awesome, I'm just getting a little thrown as a recent convert from C. In cpp I might write this as a lambda looking something like this, and pass it into std::sort:

```
{
    return a.matchesString == b.matchesString ?
    a.Val > b.Val : 
    a.matchesString ? -1 : 1;
}
```

I've failed to understand how to overcome the conflict this has with Optional. I'm wide open to solutions that have nothing to do with my thought process, or a nudge in a different direction for research.  If an iterative approach makes more sense, also let me know.

Comment: A sort is always going to be (at **best**) O(NlogN), if you do a linear search the **worst** case is O(N). Please elaborate on what you are actually wanting here (and why). Maybe you want a sequence of `Comparator.comparing().thenComparing()`; it's hard to tell.

Comment: I agree with Elliot, it really sounds like you want `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyElementType::getMatchesString).thenComparingInt(MyElementType::getValue))`.

Comment: Storing `Optinal` in a `Collection` is an antipattern. It doesn't make sense to keep optional objects which could be potentially empty. That's an [*XY problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't accumulate these optionals into a list in the first place.

Comment: I see.  The way I consume the data from the passer is already in List form, and the consumed data may or may not contain all fields necessary for processing - perhaps none of them will. I can't change my inputs, but I could change how I process them. How would you suggest iterating and pruning such a structure while looking for a particular value and sorting otherwise?  I will think on this.. it seems simple iteration makes most sense.

Comment: `data from the passer is already in List form` - you're parsing input as a `List` of `Optional` and you can't change it? `looking for a particular value and sorting otherwise` - So what is the end goal: to **find** a particular object, to **sort** the data?

Comment: Sorry, I should correct myself.  I am parsing in a List of data that may be missing fields - I can change it how I please, but the caller expects me to return an Optional String.  I am looking to *find* a particular value in field A, but if not present, I should return the largest value from fieldB.  Perhaps a sort isn't necessary, it's just how I initially attempted to handle it.

Comment: `I am parsing in a List of data that may be missing fields - I can change it how` - To answer **how** exactly, we need to know what you're parsing (JSON, XML, etc.) and what kind of library you're using for that? For instance, if you're deserializing JSON, the fields that are missing by default would be `null` (and that's fine, no need to turn them into Optional).